# How do I bind data in HTML in angular 4 since getting data in response after minutes

Tags: angular

I wanted to bind data in HTML file which I'm getting in following response. I get response in network tab but HTML not binding it in HTML. Giving me error saying Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { myService } from '../myService.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-display',
  templateUrl: './data-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-display.component.css']
})
export class dataDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
 dataDisplayResults:any=[];
 Json:any = [];
 requestURL: string = "";
 queryString:any;
 responce:any;
  constructor(private myServiceVar:myService){ 
   let re = /[?&]([^=#&]+)=([^&#]*)/g;
 let match;
 let isMatch = true;
 let matches = [];
 while (isMatch) {
     match = re.exec(window.location.href);
     if (match !== null) {
         matches[decodeURIComponent(match[1])] = decodeURIComponent(match[2]);
         if (match.index === re.lastIndex) {
             re.lastIndex++;
         }
     }
     else {
         isMatch = false;
     }
 }
 this.queryString = matches;

 this.myServiceVar.getJsonConstants().subscribe(Jsons =>
  
  this.myServiceVar.getURLResponce(Jsons.domain+Jsons.Url +"?user="+this.queryString["user"]).subscribe(respData => 
   this.dataDisplayResults = respData   
  )
    
 )
  }

  ngOnInit(){ 
   

  }

}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="dataDisplayResults.length">{{dataDisplayResults.date}}</div>
```

Comment: First, move all the content of constructor() to ngOnInit(), to keep it as light as possible. Then try <div *ngIf="dataDisplayResults">{{dataDisplayResults.date}}</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `?` avoid the length errors. if `dataDisplayResults` is undefined, It does not access the length property.

```
<div *ngIf="dataDisplayResults?.length > 0">{{dataDisplayResults.date}}</div>
```

Comment: Just a reminder: it's called elvis's operator and it's the easiest but not the best solution. You can read more https://hackernoon.com/the-angry-angular-asyncpipe-the-evil-elvis-operator-89293e37e04d

Answer (score 0):

The convention is to make any `http` call in the `ngOnInit` method. It is generally discouraged to make heavy computational work in the component constructor.
I'll suggest you to move your http call to `ngOnInit` method of the component.

However, you can also check the existence and length

```
<div *ngIf="dataDisplayResults && dataDisplayResults.length">{{dataDisplayResults.date}}</div>
```

Another thing is, you shouldn't nest the rxjs Observable subscribe call. You can use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html), switchMap etc.

```
this.myServiceVar.getJsonConstants()
       .mergeMap(Jsons => {
          return this.myServiceVar.getURLResponce(Jsons.domain+Jsons.Url +"?user="+this.queryString["user"]);
       })
       .subscribe(respData => {
             this.dataDisplayResults = respData         
       });
```